# New Improved Probabilistic version of RSA

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, number-theory

On the 2nd page of ["*New probabilistic public-key encryption based on the RSA cryptosystem*" by Roman'kov (PDF)](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~tsaban/Pdf/NewProbab.pdf), at last it says Alice can find "f" of order "l" with least probability of (1-1/l). I cannot understand how they came up with this probability.
Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: If everything else failed, contacting the author turned out to usually work quite well...

Comment: I have mailed him. But, I dont think this would work..

Comment: This looks *very* fishy. Having skimmed through the abstract and introduction, the number of incorrect statements made me stop reading.

Comment: I was trying to implement the paper, but with all these problems it is impossible to implement.

Comment: [OT:] What is that "De Gruyter" forum in which that article appeared? Could you please provide its URL?

Comment: I dont know the forum.. This paper was given to me by a professor. I just googled and found some links..http://www.degruyter.com/view/j/for

Comment: I would not take this seriously. It's presentation is certainly sub-standard. It has no proof of its arguments and is very suspect.

Comment: The paper is in De Gruyter's "Groups Complexity Cryptology", an apparently sufficiently serious scientific journal. What I currently managed with my humble poor knowledge to capture (or conjecture) from it is the following: It could provide certain security enhancements over RSA but has corresponding trade-offs: (1) while for RSA with modulus n the message space is [0, 2**n-1], the message space of the scheme with the same n is smaller (i.e. for the same message space one needs to use a larger modulus), (2) The processing is more complex. (Not surprising from the Principle of No Free Lunch.)

Comment: I have rolled your most recent edit back. Please don't try to make the same edit again. **Your question is not closed.** It can only be closed by the community or a moderator (using a dedicated mechanism) but I actually don't see any reason why it should be closed. After all it is perfectly answerable and not harmful to the quality of Crypto.SE. The fact that the paper in question is of poor quality shouldn't matter here. If you are no longer interested in obtaining an answer to your question from the Crypto.SE community, you can always _delete_ your question.

Answer (score 3):

The paper is rather sloppily written, however it can be changed into the correct statement.

The statement in the paper is:

> She takes randomly elements $f \in F^*_p$ and checks whether or not $f^{2x}=1$. With probability at least $1 − 1/\ell$ she finds $f$ of order $\ell$.

As written, that's wrong.  However, if we modify it to:

> She takes a random element $f \in F^*_p$ and computes $g = f^{2x}$; if $g \ne 1$ (which will happen with probability $1 − 1/\ell$), then $g$ will be of order $\ell$.

Then it is a correct statement (and is the standard way of generating random elements of order $\ell$).

There are a number of places in the paper like this; places where, as written, it doesn't make much sense, but if you know your number theory, you can deduce what the author actually meant.  I suspect that this can be modified to make a secure cryptosystem; however whether it does have any advantage over RSA (and whether it's actually safe for multiple users to use the same modulus and different exponents) is far less clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have now understood what was meant from that line..

Comment: An OT but related question: The author of the paper doesn't give detailed specifications of how the subgroups M and H are to be chosen, if I don't err. Couldn't the issue of appropriate vs. inappropriate choice of the subgroups eventually have some significance in the resulting security obtained?

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: you are correct; since those subgroups are exposed, a bad choice could make $pq$ easy to factor.  If I were implementing this, I would make $p-1 = 2ab$ and $q-1 = 2cd$ ($a, b, c, d$ prime), and make subgroup $M$ the one of size $ac$ and $H$ the one of size $bd$.  However, the paper doesn't say that...